# Setting UICollectionViewCell subview frames in applyLayoutAttributes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view with a custom layout.  In my cell subclass, when applyLayoutAttributes is called, I'm trying to set the frame of a background view to show a "filled" status of the cell.  Nothing I do to set the frame seems to show up.  If I set a breakpoint, I can see that the frame of the subview is what I set it to, but it doesn't show that way on the screen.

Comment: Hi @Jerry, have you found out anything about resizing frames in applyLayoutAttributes?

Comment: Nope, ended up going a different way to work around this.

Comment: I just tried changing the frame of the self.backgroundView and it seems to work? Did you try this on iOS 7.1?

Comment: Well, I wasn't trying to resize backgroundView, just another subview I had added.  I tried again on 7.1 and it still won't resize, but I think it has to do with trying to manually adjust the frame for a cell that's controlled by Autolayout.  I tried setting a constraint and that seemed to work.